# Is there an AI that can build decks?

Tags: deck-building, computer-ai

Examples of the games I have in mind are Magic: the Gathering and Pokemon Netbattle (the latter is not a traditional card game, but it does involve teambuilding so should be similar).

AI can beat the best humans at a variety of games now (most recently Go and Starcraft 2), so they are undoubtedly good players, but can they build decks? For example, can one feed an AI all the Magic: the Gathering cards [currently available in Standard](https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=legal%3Astandard) as well as the deckbuilding rules (in Magic: the Gathering, that would be "not more than 4 copies of a card per deck unless it's a basic land", "not less than 60 cards", etc) and have it tell you what the best decks are?

It sounds like a formidably hard endeavour, especially since once your list is known your opponent can "counterbuild" by adding counters vs. your specific deck, so I'm guessing there is no such AI. If that's indeed the case, I would be interested in any attempts at creating such an AI.

Comment: I would look at Kyle hills video on if it is possible to play a perfect game of magic to see why AI hasn't gone in this directions.  Especially with a game like magic you can build a deck to deal with one type of deck but would lose to another type so it is not that there is always one best decks.

Comment: This seems a challenge AI would be suited for, likely much simpler than Starcraft 2 for example.

Comment: @Styxsksu sometimes there is a "best deck", though.

Comment: @NPSF3000 Magic is Turing-complete. I doubt very much that it's simpler than Starcraft (in the general case).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 start craft is real-time, has fog of war, each unit has real world positions and can take time to move, there is geography, etc. Not familiar with magic, but comparatively it seems like a much simpler optimisation problem.

Comment: @NPSF3000 Magic games can (with certain decks) take multiple years to play.

Comment: @Allure if it is a health Meta then there shouldn't be one best deck and there is normally a little bit a flexibility with a few of the cards and that is a big problem when trying to program a computer to build the perfect deck.  The counter building is what makes magic such a great game.  You normally can build a deck to counter a strategy that might not win agonist most other decks but would beat the top deck.

Comment: @Styxsksu not every meta is healthy though (c.f. Eldrazi Winter, Aetherworks Marvel). When there is a clear best deck, the AI should ideally be able to identify what that deck is, even if it can't identify all 75 of its cards.

Comment: There are certainly ways an AI could assist. You can create a tool that assigns cards a *relative* potency (within reason) and use that to help with card selection and/or pruning. And, you can run some basic stats level and even perform a Monte Carlo analysis to maximize your gameplay *consistency*. ([MTG Deck Analyzer](https://mtg.deckanalyzer.com/) does a little of each of these). But, there's somewhat of a rock-paper-scissors mechanism in MTG. I suspect an AI would find *many* local maxima and almost never find a *clear* global maximum.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 and?  If humans can play a game for years, an AI can do it in a fraction of the time.

Comment: The Go example is more relevant than the Starcraft one. Starcraft AI's have the advantage of very precise and consistent mouse-movements that are humanly infeasible. Deckbuilding is less like that, and more like Go, in the sense that self-play seems to be the most reasonable approach. It is probably best to start with a simplified, though interesting "format". For example, one could consider the set of cards including all sliver creatures and all basic lands. It seems non-trivial to design an effective deck for this format, yet not too difficult for an AI to find something decent.

Comment: There is now, if you play MTG Commander: https://edhgen.ai

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<sup>First, just so you know where I’m coming from, I’m a professional programmer, and I’ve studied AI, but I don’t work with AI professionally, so there are limits to my expertise. I defer to anyone who *is* an expert in AI, but I think currently my expertise is most applicable to this question. That said,</sup>

There is a major constraint on the way we currently build AI, that makes its application to deck-building games intractable, at least on our current hardware.

Our general approach to AI—“machine learning”—involves the AI trying some random approach, evaluating it for effectiveness, and then doing so over, and over, and over, refining that randomness towards something better and better.

It is absolutely crucial, in this scheme, to be able to tell how good a given random try was. To learn, the AI needs to know that attempt 1354235 was better, or worse, than attempt 1354236. In a large sense, this is **all** machine learning requires, which certainly makes it very powerful, but it is a hard requirement. We need to be able to assign a number to how good a try something was, because what the AI is really doing is maximizing that number (or minimizing, whatever).

To my knowledge, no deck-building game out there enables any easy calculation of the general quality of a given deck. What do human “optimizers” of the game (e.g. pros) do? They create a deck and play it *a lot*, leveraging their considerable experience. Not just to see how it does in a variety of situations—but also to *learn how to play it*, that is, figure out the optimal strategy for playing the cards the deck makes available.

So here, for each deck, the AI wouldn’t just be able to obtain a number for how good the deck is—they’d have to have some sub-AI that’s training with that deck, learning how to optimize play with that deck. Since machine learning requires thousands or millions of iterations, having each deck iteration itself require thousands of strategy iterations just to learn how good the deck is, is going to be a **huge** problem. Our computers simply aren’t fast enough to get through all of that in a reasonable amount of time.

And there isn’t really any way around this. If you just program some game-playing ability into the AI, so it doesn’t iterate its strategy, it just tries to play, you aren’t *really* learning about the potential of each deck the AI comes up with. You’re just learning how well that deck happens to match the strategy you pre-programmed, which is probably not going to be terribly interesting or useful.

The way humans get around this is through *heuristics*—which roughly means something like “rule of thumb.” We have ideas about what is or isn’t a good idea, we can evaluate at least some options on paper as just not worth considering. Our brains are very heavily optimized for this task, and we do it constantly, considering only a tiny subset of the possibilities before us, based on our experience and understanding, to keep everything manageable. But the power of AI is to avoid these human heuristics, try out things that we never would have considered. We don’t *want* to influence or narrow the potential solution space—the whole point of this exercise is to explore it more thoroughly than a human can do.

We’re not there yet. When we have working deck-*playing* AIs for one of these games, where the AI can take a random deck and optimize playing that deck, **then** we can think about optimizing the deck-*building* part of things. But ultimately, the only way to know if you’ve built a good deck is to play it, so start there.

Comment: " Since machine learning requires thousands or millions of iterations, having each deck iteration itself require thousands of strategy iterations just to learn how good the deck is, is going to be a huge problem"

Why is this a problem different than say Chess or Starcraft?  There are more possible permutations than any computer could ever calculate.  AI is just a method of exploring the problem space and coming up with a reasonable answer using, essentially, statistics.

Comment: @NPSF3000 The difference is very simple: chess and Starcraft require that number of iterations to _play_. But we’re talking about building the deck first—and in order to test how well we built the deck, we need to then do that many iterations _for each deck_. So if we can manage *n* iterations (which are enough for chess and have been making progress with Starcraft), we now need *n* ² iterations. Since *n* was “what we can manage,” we can’t manage *n* ².

Comment: It's also that twice - not only is your deck not a constant, but neither is your opponent's deck. Playing chess is like saying "given these two fixed decks, optimise your playstyle with one against the other". It's not analogous to "make a good deck".

Comment: @RobGrant I’m assuming that the competition is decks from previous iterations, whose play has already been optimized. But true, the variety of decks that must be considered adds another factor that expands the steps necessary to optimize play.

Comment: These seem to be issues of scale, rather than fundamental barriers. I think that starting with a very limited card-pool should be tractable on even consumer level hardware. Something like standard might be feasible using a high-end server cluster. It is hard to tell this in advance, many people thought Go would be out of reach from AI for years. Besides, why would so many play iterations nessecary? The goal of most decks is consistency, to get the same hand most of the times. With a bit of clever sampling, 10 self-play iterations might already be sufficient.

Comment: Also, there are already Mtg games with computer controlled players that play a deck decently. I don't think learning to play the deck would be that complicated.

Comment: @Discretelizard You are, quite simply, wrong about the scale of the task involved. I don’t really know how I would go about proving it to you, but the number of variables here is much, much larger than anything we’ve successfully tackled with AI to date.

Comment: Sounds like Pokemon Netbattle is much easier to attack than Magic: the Gathering. There are only 9 choices per turn, and maybe 40 turns in total, but it should be relatively easy to identify who is winning at some of the leaf nodes.

Comment: "Since n was “what we can manage,” we can’t manage n ²."

We can't manage N.  The problem space of starcraft is enormous. AI in these cases is just statistics figuring out how to find a reasonable solution within those constraints.

Keep in mind Starcraft has a full map where units can go anywhere at any time. Starcraft has build orders.  These things are dynamic and can change. A starcraft AI has to be able to work against different players doing different stratergies.

In comparison, Magic does not seem any more challenging.

Comment: @NPSF3000 True; I’d had chess and go in mind with that comment. StarCraft is definitely intense for this approach.

Comment: @KRyan Perhaps. But they are merely issues of scale. These are issues where AI has kind of a track record in surpassing expectations, in particular if an organization like Google throws clever people and money at it.

Comment: @Discretelizard Yes, surpassing expectations is very much a trend in technology—but this is already me hedging my bets in deference to that. We are not remotely close here; even if we manage to maintain exponential growth, we are a long way away from the necessary scale. I suspect that “simply” scaling up won’t do it—we’ll sooner see some revolution in hardware (quantum? I am **not** knowledgeable in that realm but my impression is that it’s best for handling large combinations like this) or software (singularity?) that would enable something like this.

Comment: "where the AI can take a random deck and optimize playing that deck": It is possible to construct a Turing machine in Magic the Gathering, at least in Legacy, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09828. Therefore deciding optimal play in Magic is equivalent to the halting problem and no such AI can exist.

Comment: @CainGoldhardt _Magic_ is Turing complete, but that won’t be a problem here. We do not need to solve, in the rigorous, mathematical sense, the optimization problem, which is honestly something that almost never can be solved, often even if the system _isn’t_ Turing complete. That’s _why_ we turn to machine learning in the first place. The distinction here is that we are not attempting to determine _the optimum_, only _to optimize_, that is, through successive iterations improve our play in some meaningful sense. And that can be done. (A timeout to turn undecidable cases into ties may help.)

Comment: @Discretelizard "Perhaps. But they are merely issues of scale" - issues of scale indeed, but most of AI (and non-AI) can be handwaved away to being a way to deal with "issues of scale".

Comment: All I'm saying is that I remain unconvinced by qualitative arguments if the problem is in the quantity.

Comment: The issue pointed out in this answer is probably the main issue that's blocked the development of an AI to automatically build MtG decks. One workaround I can think of is to develop a language that can encode a strategy; and instead of developing an AI that builds a deck, develop an AI that builds a pair (deck, strategy).

Answer (score 13):

Don Goodman-Wilson made a program to build decks given a pool of cards. (I guess you could make the pool 60 copies of each card legal for the format).

From his [post on Hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/machine-learning-magic-64a6a7f864d4):

> So I started building just such a tool. Read along to find out how it works, how you can start using it, and better yet, how you can help make it awesome.

> In this article, I want to outline at a high level how I approached this challenge, how my approach works, what went well, and what didn’t. If you just want to jump directly to the code, or a deep-dive into the technical nitty-gritty for yourself, you can dig deeper on GitHub.

> In particular, I want to talk about an approach to deck building using a technique called genetic algorithms or GAs. GAs allow us to literally evolve good decks using artificial selection. Ooooooooh! Yes, it is as exciting as it sounds!

The article goes on to talk about the approach he used. And it links to a [GitHub with the source](https://github.com/DEGoodmanWilson/magique).

As the comments note, this may not be a high quality attempt nor one that handles any card set set you throw at it, but it is an attempt, as per the original post's request:

> I would be interested in any attempts at creating such an AI.

Comment: His program requires you to manually annotate how many creatures, artifacts, enchantments, instants, sorceries, and lands you wand in your deck, and most importantly requires you to manually annotate how synergistic each card is with certain archetypes. This is functionally most of the work that goes into constructing a deck in the first place. His program has no mechanism to actually read the text on each card other than mana cost and power/toughness, so would not work at all to make a deck from a new set, for example.

Comment: @BradyGilg Extracting the text from cards is an easy problem (Arena has it in a nice JSON format). The rest of your criticisms are very valid though.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Reading card text is easy, interpreting it for the purposes of deck building is not.

Answer (score 5):

### You will need a good playing-algorithm.

The most straightforward way is by running a tournament of sampled decks:

1. **Sample decks** (randomly / heuristically / using some data)
2. **Play** many games using identical playing-algorithm. This way the only difference are the decks.
3. **Keep the winner**(s).

---

bypass: sample strong decks from a DB (for example: [hearthstone top decks](https://www.hearthstonetopdecks.com/)).

Comment: This sounds like a "here's how it could be done" rather than an answer to the question (examples or examples of attempts).

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson, you have a point but my answer is not just a theoretical hypothesis. I think that If I will look hard enough I will find algorithms that work exactly that.

Comment: ... decks don't play each other. People play decks.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus The "many times" constraint somewhat implies that the decks will be played by a computer rather than a human. I doubt that will be too much of a problem, given how strong MCTS algorithms have become at card games like Magic.

Comment: @Stef - just because the work has already been done, doesn't make it trivial work.

Comment: @Stef is there Magic-playing AI that can match the best players in the world? If so, can you point me to results?

Comment: @ArcanistLupus, People can not play many times.  Algorithms do. For example, Alpha Star agents played up to 200 years of StarCraft.   https://deepmind.com/blog/article/alphastar-mastering-real-time-strategy-game-starcraft-ii

Comment: @Allure I haven't been following that close; maybe you can find interesting research papers on google scholar: [scholar.google.com/?q=magic the gathering ai](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=magic%20the%20gathering%20ai) or on DBLP: [dblp.uni-trier.de/search?q=magic+the+gathering](https://dblp.uni-trier.de/search?q=magic+the+gathering)

Answer (score -1):

### ChatGPT can do this, but not terribly well.

ChatGPT is a text generation AI that's been trained to statistically generate the miat likely text based on a corpus of writing that is basically the entire Internet.

This includes a whole bunch of Magic: the Gathering deck lists.

As a result, if you ask it to build you a MtG deck list, it will happily do so for you. It will promptly give you the statistically most likely text for your prompt, which will most likely be a list of competitively viable MtG cards.

Whether that deck would be good (or even legal) is something that it's not capable of judging, however, since it doesn't understand anything about the actual game, and it's not capable of doing things like counting how many cards it's putting into your deck or understanding that a card that used to be strong has now been banned.

It's just generating text based off of the text that humans who are capable of playing the game have made.

Comment: ChatGPT can do this, but terribly bad

Comment: Hi. Interesting, but is there any reason to believe that the produced deck would be any better than the human-made decks that it takes inspiration from? In fact, is there any reason to believe that it wouldn't be *much worse* that the human-made decks that it takes inspiration from? Note that you could also take a database of human-made decks, and try to randomly combine these decks into a new deck using a "very dumb" algorithm; is there any reason to believe that ChatGPT would do any better than this random algorithm?

Comment: Note that my question in the previous comment is not a rhetorical question; I'd be happy of an answer to it along the lines of "someone has put some reasonable effort into trying to use ChatGPT for this and here are their results".

Comment: ChatGPT is also quite likely to not make a (legal) deck, just a bunch of words that sound like one. What do you do if it uses a name that isn't a real card, or suggests 5 Griselbrands?

Comment: @Caleth I've given it a shot a few times, and I haven't gotten any made-up cards or decks with too many copies of a given card yet. I have gotten a deck with 65 cards, though, because ChatGPT can't count.

Comment: ChatGPT can't build decks with cards it's never seen before (e.g. new set release) though, can it?

Comment: @Allure Nothing post-2021 unless they've upgraded it with more recent data, no. It can do Modern decks, though.

Answer (score -3):

I put together this site that provides recommendations based on an existing set of cards that you have on your deck. Seems to be working well! Any feedback is welcome: https://swampgpt.pythonanywhere.com/

EDIT: I hope that this is a better answer. I used ChatGPT creating my own GPT by adding information from Magic cards and providing instructions to the GPT that describe MTG synergies as well as things to avoid. The rest is built with Python as well as Java and HTML. I hope this helps! I am currently working on improving the functionalities of the website.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi! Intriguing. Could you describe a bit the algorithms you used?

Comment: +1. I gave the algorithm Psychatog & Island + Swamp and it gave me some amusing (and sensible) responses of synergistic cards - although it's still very far from a complete decklist.